# Keep counting for timeout with select() while receiving messages?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

`select()` returns -1 on error, and 0 on timeout, and the number of the descriptors in the set on success.

Suppose we have the following pseudocode:

```
while(1){
    int s = select(..., &timeout); //timeout = 5 sec

    if (s < 0) { perror(...); }

    else if(s == 0) { //timeout }

    else {
        //wait for some recv event or STDIN
    }
}
```

I recognized that the process waits either until timeout, or until some recv event occurs.

I need to have it keep counting for the specified time while receiving from an arbitrary number of peers only using select().

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you're asking..."need to have it keep counting", but I don't see *any* counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux, the `select` system call decrements the timeout value by the amount of time elapsed. Posix allows but does not require this behaviour, which makes it hard to rely on; portable code should assume that `timeout`'s contents are unspecified when the `select` call returns.

The only really portable solution is to start by computing the absolute time you want the timeout to expire, and then check the time before each subsequent call to select in order to compute the correct timeout value. Beware of clocks which might run backwards (or skip forwards); `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is usually your best bet.

Comment: @user2418202: that's why I mentioned the linux-specific behaviour. On linux, just don't reset timeout and it will  automatically count-down to 0. It would have been nice if Posix had required that behaviour or defined an alternate interface with that behaviour but it didn't. There is a trick using a pipe, a child process and a second select call in the child  but its imprecise because of the difficulty of synching the child without a clock

Comment: I am so sorry. I had to read your answer more carefully. That works perfectly.